# Find infimum of $S = {\frac{2}{n^2}+(-1)^n \,| \,\,n\in\mathbb N}$

Tags: calculus

Find infimum of $S = {\frac{2}{n^2}+(-1)^n \,| \,\,n\in\mathbb N}$

What I have done:

$$S = {1, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{9}{8}, ...}$$

Since $1\in S$ then $infS = 1$

Let $m=1$

$$\frac{2}{n^2}+(-1)^n > 1$$ so this means that 1 is a lower bound of S

if $m'>1$ (Trying to show that $m'$ is not a lower bound of S)

$$\frac{2}{n^2}+(-1)^n < m'$$ $$\implies \frac{2}{n^2} < m' + (1)^n$$

Because $\frac{2}{n^2} > 0$ and $m' + 1^n > 0$ then by the reciprocal rule,

$$\frac{n^2}{2}>\frac{1}{m'+(1)^n}$$ 
$$\implies n^2 > \frac{2}{m'+(1)^n}$$
$$\implies n > \sqrt{\frac{2}{m'+(1)^n}}$$

Thus by the archimedean property of $R$ there is a $n_o > \sqrt{\frac{2}{m'+(1)^n}}$

Then, $\frac{2}{n^2}+(-1)^n < m', \,\, \frac{2}{n^2}+(-1)^n\in S$ thus, $m'$ is not a lower bound of S so then the infimum of S is 1.

I've been told that the infimum does not exist but I am not sure where I went wrong. If anyone can help me figure out where I possibly might of went wrong that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspection, even terms decrease to $1$ and odd terms decrease to $-1$. So the infimum is $-1$.